# How to fix "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)" error in C

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind, cs50

I'm struggling with memory management while trying to create a trie database in C that loads a dictionary and checks a given text for any misspellings. The code compiles and runs but valgrind returns an error saying that I am touching memory that is uninitialized. However, I thought that using malloc would suffice.

I've tried to set all the created nodes to NULL but it still tells me I am not initializing them.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <type.h>

#include "dictionary.h"


#define N 27

// Represents a node in a trie
typedef struct node
{
    bool is_word;
    struct node *children[N];
}
node;

// Represents a trie
node *root;

// Loads dictionary into memory
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    SIZE = 0;
    // Initialize trie
    root = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    root->is_word = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        root->children[i] = NULL;
    }

    // Open dictionary
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        unload();
        return false;
    }

    // Buffer for a word
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    node *head = root;

    // Insert words into trie
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        int i = 0;
        head = root;
        while (word[i])
        {
            int box = word[i] - 'a';
            if (head->children[box] == NULL)
            {
                head->children[box] = malloc(sizeof(node));
            }
            else
            {
                head = head->children[box];
                i++;
            }
        }
        head->is_word = true;
        SIZE++;

    }
    // Close dictionary

    fclose(file);

    // Indicate success

    return true;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory
bool unload(void)
{
    void destroy(node *head);
    node *head = root;
    destroy(head);
    head = NULL;
    root = NULL;
    return true;
}

// Recursively destroys all nodes from last to first.
void destroy(node *head)
{
    for (int i = 0, n = N; i < n; i++)
    {

        // Checks if the current node points to NULL, and stops the func if it does.
        if (head->children[i] == NULL)
        {
            continue;
        }

        // Runs this function again if the current node points to another.
        destroy(head->children[i]);
        head->children[i] = NULL;
        head->is_word = false;
    }
}
```

I expected that valgrind would return no memory leaks since I thought I correctly allocated and subsequently freed memory by setting all my created nodes to NULL. Here is an example of the errors I'm getting:

```
==1529== 
==1529== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1529==    at 0x4013A4: destroy (dictionary.c:151)
==1529==    by 0x4013C0: destroy (dictionary.c:157)
==1529==    by 0x4013C0: destroy (dictionary.c:157)
==1529==    by 0x4011CC: unload (dictionary.c:140)
==1529==    by 0x400DB9: main (speller.c:154)
==1529==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==1529==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1529==    by 0x401136: load (dictionary.c:70)
==1529==    by 0x400914: main (speller.c:41)
==1529== 
==1529== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1529==    at 0x4013A4: destroy (dictionary.c:151)
==1529==    by 0x4013C0: destroy (dictionary.c:157)
==1529==    by 0x4011CC: unload (dictionary.c:140)
==1529==    by 0x400DB9: main (speller.c:154)
==1529==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==1529==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind./vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1529==    by 0x401136: load (dictionary.c:70)
==1529==    by 0x400914: main (speller.c:41)
==1529== 
Killed
```

I apologize in advance if I am not explaining this very well or if the answer is obvious, I am a newcomer to programming.

// UPDATE

I've successfully corrected the initialization error thanks to 1201ProgramAlarm's suggestion. Valgrind is now giving me an error indicating that I have a memory leak. I will try to initialize my functions outside of the other functions like many have suggested and see if that solves it.

// EDIT 2

Here is the new function I utilized to correct the initialization error:

```
node *AllocateNode(void)
{
    node *head = root;
    head = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        free(head);
        return false;
    }
    head->is_word = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        head->children[i] = NULL;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Here is the new error that valgrind is giving me:

```
==19546== 
==19546== HEAP SUMMARY:
==19546==     in use at exit: 1,344 bytes in 6 blocks
==19546==   total heap usage: 383,133 allocs, 383,127 frees, 81,995,696 bytes allocated
==19546== 
==19546== 1,344 (672 direct, 672 indirect) bytes in 3 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==19546==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19546==    by 0x40121F: AllocateNode (dictionary.c:170)
==19546==    by 0x40113F: load (dictionary.c:74)
==19546==    by 0x400914: main (speller.c:41)
==19546== 
==19546== LEAK SUMMARY:
==19546==    definitely lost: 672 bytes in 3 blocks
==19546==    indirectly lost: 672 bytes in 3 blocks
==19546==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19546==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19546==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19546== 
==19546== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==19546== ERROR SUMMARY: 4541 errors from 8 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: You should avoid declaring functions inside other functions (like you're doing inside `unload()`), put all your declaration at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Valgrind reports problems at line 151 in dictionary.c, but you hace given us only 111 lines of source code, and you did not even tell us whether they came from dictionary.c or some other file. How should we know what is at line 151? Post a [mcve] with matching error messages.

Comment: It does look like when `load` allocates a new node, in `head->children[box] = malloc(sizeof(node))`, it does not do anything to initialize it other than `head->is_word = true;`. So the elements in `head->children` are left uninitialized.

Comment: A strong suggestion — do not declare functions inside other functions, as you do with `destroy()` in `unload()`.  In general, that leads to multiple declarations for the same function, and it is much harder to change all those declarations if you need to change the interface to a function.  From a maintainability standpoint, it is a bad idea.  You can use GCC option `-Wnested-externs` to have such declarations flagged automatically.

Comment: Voting to close it as a typo. OP acknowledges that all children should be initialized to NULL, but obviously that is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because a `node` needs to be initialized after it is allocated, but you don't have one place to do that so you miss that step in some of your node allocations.

What you should do is take the 10 lines of code from `load` from right after the `// Initialize trie` comment and put them in a function.  This code allocates space for a node and initializes all of its members.  Then, rather than repeating this code (or even calling `malloc`), call your new function.  Everywhere you're currently calling `malloc(sizeof(node))`, replace that call with a call to your new function.  In particular, the `head->children[box] = malloc(sizeof(node));` line would then be `head->children[box] = AllocateNode();`.

With just the call to `malloc` there, none of the fields in the allocated node are initialized, and the various pointers in the `children` array can have any value in them.  When you use these uninitialized values in `destroy` anything can happen.  In this case valgrind is telling you of the problem.

Comment: This seems to have fixed my initialization error. Thank you.

Now, however, valgrind is telling me that my new AllocateNode() function has a memory leak. I've tried freeing the function itself but that didn't fix it. I'll update my post to show the error I'm getting.